# Loop in python for different steps size

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, threshold

I do some program which will calculate numbers of values higher than some threshold (Th) but only after it is 3 in line and till the value is less than Th but also 3 in line. In my logic after the program detects 3 values > Th it starts to calculate till 3 values will not be less than Th after that `i=k` and a new loop start from a number, not `i++`  but from `i = i+k`, my program is not working right.
Do you have any idea why? I need numbers of `values > Th` but if it is some single fluctuating it shouldn't be calculated. Maybe you can understand better if you look at the picture. For me is an interesting **number of values beetwin these 3 solid markers.**
[image]

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([10, 2, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 0, 5, 6, 7])
b = np.array([0])

Th = 1
k = 0
i = 0
for i in range(len(a) - 3):

    if a[i] and a[i + 1] and a[i + 2] > Th:

        while a[i] or a[i + 1] or a[i + 2] > Th:
            k += 1
            print("a: ", a[i])
            print("k: ", k)
            i += 1
    i = i + k
```

Comment: being the last statement in the loop, `i = i + k` has virtually no affect on the useful value of `i` as it is immediately being re-assigned the next value from the `range` object by the `for` loop. Maybe use another `while` loop (which seems to be more idiomatic in this case anyway)

Comment: `x and y > z` doesn’t mean what you think it does.